# XCTest で `setUp` が呼出されない

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, objective-c, テスト

XCTestをしようとしているのですが、下記のコードで`setUp`も`testExample`も呼び出されません。

```
import XCTest

class HogeTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
        XCTAssert(true)
    }

    func testPerformanceExample() {
        // This is an example of a performance test case.
        measure {
            // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
        }
    }

}
```

ひし形の再生ボタンを押下するとビルドされ実機でアプリが起動します。
Xcodeは下記の状態がしばらく続いて、その後Test Failedになり、アプリが落ちます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

なにかここを見てみれば？などがあれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: このURLのドキュメントにあるように、テストコードのXCTestCaseを継承したクラスは左側に表示されます。ここに`HogeTests`は表示されていますか？ https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/01-introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました！回答していただいた方はありがとうございました！
原因はテストターゲットにProvisioningProfileが設定されていないためでした。
下記が参考になりました！！

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381291/unable-to-run-xctests-on-ios-device